# Extension to a different base of an inequality (upper bound) to the hyperbolic cosine

Tags: inequality, taylor-expansion, hyperbolic-functions

For any $a\in\mathbb{R}$, it is pretty straightforward to show, using the Maclaurin series for $e^a$ and $\cosh(a)$ that

$$
\cosh(a) \le e^{a^2/2}
$$

I would like to show a similar bound for
$$
\frac{b^a + b^{-a}}{2}
$$
for $b>1$, which one could interpret as the hyperbolic cosine with a different basis.
I hoped for 
$$
\frac{b^a + b^{-a}}{2} \le b^{a^2/2}
$$
but I cannot show it (which does not mean it cannot be shown, btw).

Is there any other bound available? 
I know I could get $b^{|a|}$, but since $a$ is likely to be in $(-1,1)$,  would prefer something with higher exponent for $a$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try $b=4$ and $a=1$. Then
$$
\frac{b^a+b^{-a}}2=\frac{17}8\gt2=b^{a^2/2}\tag{1}
$$
which shows that $\frac{b^a+b^{-a}}2\le b^{a^2/2}$ is not true for all $b\gt1$.

---

If we know that $\frac{e^a+e^{-a}}2\le e^{a^2/2}$, then
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{b^a+b^{-a}}2
&=\frac{e^{a\log(b)}+e^{-a\log(b)}}2\\
&\le e^{(a\log(b))^2/2}\\[5pt]
&=b^{\log(b)a^2/2}\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$
and if $1\le b\le e$, then $(2)$ implies
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{b^a+b^{-a}}2
&\le b^{\log(b)a^2/2}\\
&\le b^{a^2/2}\tag{3}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Yes, in the end I arrived to the same bound. I hoped for something that would hold for $b>e$, and stricter than (2).

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$$b^a=e^{a\log b}$$

and

$$\cosh(x)=\frac{e^x+e^{-x}}{2}$$